# Display resultset in tabular format -- in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following table:

```
user_id    document_id    date
------------------------------------
1           1             2016-01-01
1           2             2016-01-01
1           3             2016-01-02
2           4             2016-01-01
2           5             2016-01-02
3           6             2016-01-02
3           7             2016-01-02
3           8             2016-01-02
3           9             2016-01-03
3          10             2016-01-03
3          11             2016-01-04
3           9             2016-01-04
```

Is it possible to - in SQL - get the number of documents viewed, per user per day, in tabular format?

```
date          user_id_1    user_id_2    user_3
----------------------------------------------
2016-01-01    2            1            0
2016-01-02    1            1            3
2016-01-03    0            0            2
2016-01-04    0            0            2
```

Normally I would use any scripting language to create this by looping through a resultset, but in this particular case I can't. Because of restrictions, I only have access to SQL server.

If this is even possible, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server pivot".

Comment: [one step further](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20pivot), [two steps further](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Are users limited in the amount? or there can be infinity users?

Comment: you could use pivot if possible dates are limited and known...but i don't think this is the case, isn't it?

Comment: No it's not. The number of dates and users are unlimited.

Comment: You have only access to SQL server, but you can write and run a script, can't you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: @alessalessio SQL scripts, yes. I mean, no other scripts. Usually, I would loop through the resultset in Powershell for instance, and write the table to a file.

Comment: I would use GROUP and then create the table in the language I am using it in. If you want a pure SQL solution, the linked article gives you the exact solution.

Comment: it will be helpful for you if you post this question in [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "The number of dates and users are unlimited" would mean unlimited number of columns, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't know how your table is called, so I call it `[YourTableNameGoesHere]`:

```
DECLARE @userstring AS nvarchar(max),
        @columns AS nvarchar(max),
        @sql AS nvarchar(max)

SELECT @userstring = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename([user_id]) from [YourTableNameGoesHere] for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
SELECT @columns = '[date],' + stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename([user_id]) + ' as ' + quotename('user_id_'+CAST([user_id] as nvarchar(10))) from [YourTableNameGoesHere] for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

SELECT @sql = '
select '+@columns+'
from (select [date],
            [user_id],
            document_id
        from [YourTableNameGoesHere]) src 
pivot (COUNT(document_id) for [user_id] in ('+@userstring+')
) pvt'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

The output is:

```
date       user_id_1   user_id_2   user_id_3
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2016-01-01 2           1           0
2016-01-02 1           1           3
2016-01-03 0           0           2
2016-01-04 0           0           2

(4 row(s) affected)
```